# concatenate two lines in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate two lines in a data frame. Here is my data frame

```
  book1  book2  book3  book4
  0   1     nan     3      5
  1   nan   genre   nan    1
```

and here is the result I want: changing only on columns book4 and book2

```
        book1  book2  book3  book4
      0   1     genre     3    1
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
In [1190]: import numpy as np

In [1191]: df1 = df.T
In [1197]: df1[0] = np.where(df1[1].notna(), df1[1], df1[0])

In [1200]: df = df1[0].to_frame().T

In [1201]: df
Out[1201]: 
  book1  book2 book3 book4
0     1  genre     3     1
```